# How to access state values in sepearate .js files using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, scope, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a simple web app where the user enters an authors name and this sends a request to the NYT book review API which will then return a list of all the NYT reviews for that author. I'm using this as a learning experience to get to grips with React but I am completely stumped. My code is the following:

**app.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import AuthorInput from './components/AuthorInput'
import ReviewList from './components/ReviewList'

function App(){
    return (
        <>
            <AuthorInput />
            <ReviewList />
        </>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

**AuthorInput.js**

```
import React,{useState, useRef} from 'react'
import '../styles/main.scss'

function AuthorInput(){
    
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
    const searchField = useRef(null);

    function getURL(){
        const urlSearchValue = encodeURIComponent(searchValue.trim()); 
        const userURL = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/reviews.json?author=${urlSearchValue}MY_API_KEY`

        return userURL  
    } 

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        searchField.current.focus()
        getURL() 
        setSearchValue("")
    } 
    
    return(
        <>
            <div className = "author-search">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action = "">
                    <label>Enter authors name:</label><br></br>
                    <input 
                    ref={searchField}  
                    value={searchValue}
                    onChange = {setSearchValue(e.target.value)}  
                    type = "text"
                    placeholder = "e.g. David Mitchell"
                    />
                    <button>Submit</button>

                </form>

            </div>
        </>
    )
} 

export default AuthorInput
```

I'm wanting to use the returned URL value (from the getURL() function in AuthorInput.js) when the user inputs an authors name for use in a sepearte file (ReviewList.js) to fetch the data and create a list. This API seems to need user input (i.e. author name) before the data can be fetched. Is there a way I can access this URL value or is how I'm currently going about it making it not possible?

Comment: Hey @Quinesi, I do not completely understand what you want to do. Do you want to use the "searchValue" in some other file or the URL? Or the returned data of an Fetch?

Comment: Hey Carlotta, thanks for getting back to me - the answers below have solved it for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function that updates data in the parent. Checkout the example below:

> App Component

```
function App(){
    const [userUrl, setUserUrl] = useState("");
    
    return (
        <>
            <AuthorInput onUrlChange={latestUserUrl => setUserUrl(latestUserUrl)} />
            <ReviewList userUrl={userUrl} />
        </>
    )
}
```

> AuthorInput component

```
function AuthorInput({onUrlChange}){
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
    const searchField = useRef(null);
    
    const updateUrlValue = (author) => {
        const urlSearchValue = encodeURIComponent(author.trim());
        const userURL = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/reviews.json?author=${urlSearchValue}MY_API_KEY`

        setSearchValue(author);
        onUrlChange(userURL); // function is provided by the parent component(App)
    }

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        searchField.current.focus()
        getURL()
        updateUrlValue("")
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div className = "author-search">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action = "">
                    <label>Enter authors name:</label><br></br>
                    <input
                        ref={searchField}
                        value={searchValue}
                        onChange = {e => updateUrlValue(e.target.value)}
                        type = "text"
                        placeholder = "e.g. David Mitchell"
                    />
                    <button>Submit</button>

                </form>

            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default AuthorInput
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor you code in following way

You can create components for specific use ie. `AuthorInput` will do the work of getting input from user. `ReviewList` will display all the data list fetched from API.

App.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import AuthorInput from './components/AuthorInput'
import ReviewList from './components/ReviewList'

function App(){
    const [booksList,setBooksList] = useState([]);

    const fetchBooksList = (url) => {
       fetch(url)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(data => setBooksList(data))
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <AuthorInput fetchBooksList={fetchBooksList}/>
            <ReviewList booksList={booksList}/>
        </>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

AuthorInputComponent

```
import React,{useState, useRef} from 'react'
import '../styles/main.scss'

function AuthorInput({fetchBooksList }){
    
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
    const searchField = useRef(null);

    function getURL(){
        const urlSearchValue = encodeURIComponent(searchValue.trim()); 
        const userURL = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/reviews.json?author=${urlSearchValue}MY_API_KEY`
        return userURL  
    } 

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        searchField.current.focus();
        fetchBooksList(getURL());
        setSearchValue("");
    } 
    
    return(
        <>
            <div className = "author-search">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action = "">
                    <label>Enter authors name:</label><br></br>
                    <input 
                    ref={searchField}  
                    value={searchValue}
                    onChange ={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}  
                    type = "text"
                    placeholder = "e.g. David Mitchell"
                    />
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default AuthorInput
```

And for `ReviewList` component you can simply display the fetched data passed through prop

Comment: Thank you for this! Yours and Maarten's methods solved the issue and highlighted the fact that I need to read up a bit more on how props work!